# Could not load type ASP.ViewSwitcher

Tags: c#, asp.net, friendly-url, asp.net-webpages

I added `FriendlyUrls` package via NuGet to my asp.net web pages project.

When I debug the solution it returns error that `ASP.ViewSwitcher` in `ViewSwitcher.ascx` could not load.

I did not find anything on the internet about this issue.

Could anybody please help me, how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
  CodeBehind="Site.Mobile.master.cs" Inherits="ASP.Site_Mobile" %>
```

to

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
  CodeFile="Site.Mobile.master.cs" Inherits="ASP.Site_Mobile" %>
```

(Edit) 
That is the case if you are working on a website as oppose to a web application.

Comment: That was the problem in my case, thanks man! It is a WebSite with mixed WinForms and MVC 4

Comment: BTW, I needed to make this `CodeBehind` -> `CodeFile` modification both in the added `Site.Mobile.master` template and the `ViewSwitcher.ascx`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Thanks to user3260977. I'm going to elaborate what he told.

Once you have installed `FriendlyUrls` package, there will be a file called `Site.Mobile.Master`. Double click and open it. Change `CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"` to `CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"`. Now open the file `ViewSwitcher.ascx` and change `CodeBehind="ViewSwitcher.ascx.cs"` to `CodeFile="ViewSwitcher.ascx.cs"`.

Basically change every file where there is `CodeBehind` to `CodeFile`.

Answer (score 0):

try importing the namespace

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls" %>
```

Comment: Does not help. It still return error. I deleted the viewswitcher.ascx and site.mobile.master files from the project and everything works fine. But won't there be some problems on mobile devices?